# Is there anyway I can save WebView content in the app, so when I open the app again it open faster

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this Swift code to load my website content in iOS app.

However, whenever I open the app it takes long time until the website load

So, is there anyway I can save the UIWebView content, so whenever I open the app, loading time becomes less

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var WebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "website address")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        WebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe. You *can* take an image of things - but that assumes quite a few things. Is the *content* static? Is the *entire* page visible? And for sure, that begs the question - why would you want to do this? Speed up the server serving the page instead. (At least consider that.)

Comment: This depend actually on what takes long time - communication with server(networking) or showing of webpage content(rendering) ? In first case, yes you can do somthing - like implement some kind of caching system which stored you web page data, but in second case I'm not sure if you can do much.

Comment: I have a website and a mobile version of that website, so I thought using this method to build a website app would e much easier than building an app from zero

Comment: Actually loading the webpage content is the part that take long time, therefore, I thought if there is a method to save that contents of the start page as cach at the device after first time use, then, opening the app another time will be easier and faster

Comment: the server response time is really good. However, loading the Homepage after opening the app is the part that takes long time. so it seems that saving the homepage content after each use might be helpful

Comment: You can use a network proxy such as Charles Proxy to examine the communications and potentially determine the problem. For example, if you are trying to load any sort of high-res image that would take a long time and if that's the case you can try to save that image to the disk and then next time you open the app you can load it locally. I would highly recommend using charles proxy to determine what the problem is. You should also check the URL cache policy. That would definitely help too. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy

Comment: You're talking about caching. `UIWebView` doesn't let you control that. `WKWebView` does, so it might be what you need.

Comment: Yes as UIWebView is deprecated I would advise looking into WKWebView.

Comment: Yes WKWebView works well, Many thanks :)